# Parallelize[MapIndexed[...,Association[...]]] returns broken result

Tags: bugs, parallelization, associations, map

**Bug introduced in 10.0.2 or earlier and persisting through 12.0**

---

> **Confirmed:** CASE:4041910

Consider the following example:

```
MapIndexed[f[##, $KernelID]&, <|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3|>]
(* <|a -> f[1, {Key[a]}, 0], b -> f[2, {Key[b]}, 0], c -> f[3, {Key[c]}, 0]|> *)
```

Now lets try to `Parallelize` this:

```
Parallelize@MapIndexed[f[##, $KernelID]&, <|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3|>]
(* ---- Output in Mathematica 11.2 - 11.3 ---- *)
(* Association[f[a -> 1, {1}, 2], f[b -> 2, {2}, 2], f[c -> 3, {3}, 1]] *)

(* ---- Output in Mathematica 10 - 11.1.1 ---- *)
(* Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {<|a->1,b->2,c->3|>,{{1},{2},{3}}} cannot be transposed. >> *)
(* Transpose[f[<|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3|>, {{1}, {2}, {3}}, 4]] *)
```

Clearly, this is completely broken - it doesn't simply switch to sequential evaluation, the output is actually useless.

How can one work around this issue until it gets fixed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Workaround

Wolfram support suggested the following workaround until the issue is resolved:

```
Parallelize@Map[First, MapIndexed[Hold[f[##, $KernelID]]&, <|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3|>]]
(* <|a -> f[1, {Key[a]}, 2], b -> f[2, {Key[b]}, 2], c -> f[3, {Key[c]}, 1]|> *)
```

which is working. This is because the expressions to be evaluated are built sequentially (but wrapped in `Hold`). The evaluation (by means of `First`/`ReleaseHold`) is then done using `ParallelMap[…]`/`Parallelize[Map[…]]`

### Fix

While the above is a nice workaround, it's still something that has to be remembered. The following code fixes the issue globally.

#### Mathematica 11 & 12

```
Begin["Parallel`Evaluate`Private`"];
Unprotect@MapIndexed;
HoldPattern[tryCombine[MapIndexed[f_, str_Association], opts___]] ^:= 
 ParallelCombine[MapIndexed[f], str, opts]
Protect@MapIndexed;
End[];
```

To verify:

```
Parallelize@MapIndexed[f[##, $KernelID] &, <|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3|>]
(* <|a -> f[1, {Key[a]}, 4], b -> f[2, {Key[b]}, 3], c -> f[3, {Key[c]}, 2]|> *)
```

This works by adding a special case for the problematic case (`Parallelize[MapIndexed[…,<|…|>]]`) to the code that handles the parallelization internally. Since `ParallelCombine` supports associations and associations can be `Join`ed, the actual implementation is trivial (since we don't have to add the position specification manually).

#### Mathematica 10 (works also for 11)

```
Begin["Parallel`Evaluate`Private`"];
Unprotect@MapIndexed;
tryCombine[MapIndexed[f_, str_Association], opts___] ^:= 
 ParallelCombine[MapIndexed[f, <|#|>] &, Normal@str, opts]
Protect@MapIndexed;
End[];
```

The only difference to the above fix is that `ParallelCombine` doesn't seem to support associations in 10, so we have to convert it to a list first. Of course this will also work for Mathematica 11+, but it feels like an unnecessary step to covert to a list first.